# Fireplace pilot light lights but logs will not ignite

Tags: gas

When I turn the knob to on, the pilot light goes out.  The technician tried lighting it with his torch and still would not light the logs.  Said it was the pressure regulator. Switched that out to a two stage regulator and still the same problem.  Could there be something in the gas line?

Comment: I hope the tech was not heating the thermocouple with a torch that can damage them infact cause them to explode as the air chamber is fixed. Do you hear the gas turn on to the logs? I have seen a small amount of moisture in a gas valve cause problems but not the regulator usually  (gas company or propane first /2nd stage)  “the technician” what kind of technician?  Gas company wood stove company? Did he burp the gas line? Ie open it for a second to verify flow?  It sounds like water in the gas valve itself. And that can be blown out with air. More info on the type of gas and the outside temps

Comment: Thank you, Ed. No, I don't hear the gas turn on to the logs. The tech. was with the propane gas company so I assumed he knew what he was doing(?). This is on a 100lb propane cylinder which I recently purchased and had filled at Ace Hardware. Outside temp is around 40 degrees here.

Comment: I have had trouble with one of my large tanks low flow with the safety over fill valves. This valve has a safety so it can not be turned on with out the gas fitting in place. This one maybe have had a plastic piece fall out that opens the flow when the fitting is in place. I had an oring that size and glued it to the the piece carefully and it has worked like that for 5 years. It’s not part of the seal but a safety and it still works so check that and if not,, To me it sounds like a thermocouple more than a gas valve. But the valve on the tank or TC would be my targets 40f at start should work

Comment: Thank you all for your replies. I will check these suggestions out.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it being a new tank that the safety valve is not opening properly. I have 1 tank that has this problem with the gas fitting in place it is not opening enough to provide full flow for the patio heater.
After figuring out what the cause was I put a drop of super glue on a fat oring the same size and stuck it in place and it has worked for 5 years.
It is not in the sealing surface.
You might want to take the tank back I had purchased the tank and filled it but did not use it until a year later, but if you recently purchased I would consider taking it back.